# Live action movie on the Disney channel about a boy, shown around 2008-2010

Tags: story-identification, movie, disney

This is a movie i used to watch when I was a kid. The movie is around 90 minutes, is live-action, and was shown on the Disney Channel. Important context is that I watched this on the Indonesian version of the Disney Channel. (It wasn't an Indonesian production)

I'm not sure if the movie was produced by Disney, just that I saw it on the Disney channel. I'm pretty sure it featured an East asian boy as the main character.

I honestly don't really remember much from the movie, as I last saw it a very long time ago.

I'm not sure if it was freshly produced around 2008-2010, or if it was a re-run from an old production. But I do feel like it wasn't an old movie (at least 2000+).

If I'm not wrong, he also had friends that weren't human. I'm not sure if his friends were animated or realistic.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. This is very sparse on details at the moment. Can you please take a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335) and [edit] in any extra info you remember?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. For example, what were his non-human friends? Were they animated or live-action? Where did he live? What were their names? Did they live with their parents or on their own? Were there any girl characters?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. Sorry, I saw this movie very very early into my life (5-6 years old,) so it really is almost impossible to recall any details about the movie. Even worse is that I most likely did not speak the language the movie was in. About the checklist, I do not remember anything. I saw it 2008-2010, not sure how old it was other than it being relatively new (2000+), and I don't know what language it was in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***[The Secret of the Magic Gourd](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0496386/)*** (2007).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Secret_of_the_Magic_Gourd_(2007_film)):

> *The Secret of the Magic Gourd* (Chinese: 宝葫芦的秘密), or *The Magic Gourd*, is a live-action/CGI animation movie made in 2007 by Centro in co-operation with China Movie Co Ltd and Disney. It is the second film based on a 1958 novel by Zhang Tianyi after the 1963 film.
>
> *The Secret of the Magic Gourd* is Disney's first CGI/animation full-length feature film produced for the Chinese mainland market.
>
> The films DVD release date in the United States was on January 27, 2009. The English dubbed version of the film features Corbin Bleu as the voice of the Magic Gourd and Drake Johnston as the voice of Raymond.

From the [Disney Wiki](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/The_Secret_of_the_Magic_Gourd):

> The Secret of the Magic Gourd follows the wondrous adventures of a 6th grade young schoolboy named Wang Bao. When Wang Bao discovers a magical gourd that can instantly grant his every wish, the awkward child suddenly becomes a hero amongst his curious classmates. When the gourd proves more of a burden than a blessing and the boy decides to get rid of it, he quickly discovers that's easier said than done.

Comment: Yes, this is it, thank you so much for the answer. How do I mark the question as solved? And how did you find it, if I may ask?